# @insert not working room database in RecyclerView adapter

Tags: android, android-room, android-recyclerview, android-livedata

I'm trying to insert recyclerView item by clicking inside the database with @insert method
now after the clicking i'm getting the Strings a,b but whenever I put `Viewmodel.insert(new FavNews(String a,String b)` i'm getting null...!
where should  my code or am I putting it in the wrong place wrong thread ?

```
public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.NewsViewHolder> {

 Context context;
 ArrayList<Result> articles;


 public NewsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Result> articles) {
this.context = context;
this.articles = articles;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public NewsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.news_fragment_items, parent, false);
return new  NewsViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NewsViewHolder holder, final int position) {
holder.tvName.setText(articles.get(position).getWebTitle());
holder.tvDesCription.setText(articles.get(position).getSectionName());




holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
             //here need to put insert method

    }
});
 }

     @Override
     public int getItemCount() {
   return articles.size();
 }

public class NewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

TextView tvName;
TextView tvDesCription;

public NewsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    tvName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    tvDesCription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDesCription);


}
 }
 }
```

this is the viewModel

```
  public class NoteViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {


private NewsRepository repository;
private LiveData<List<FavNews>> allNotes;



 public MutableLiveData<NewsResponse> getNewsRepository() {
   repository = NewsRepository.getInstance();
return repository.getNews( "b70d396f-d5b4-43f0-8b67-222524937f25");
}

 public NoteViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    repository = new NewsRepository(application);
    allNotes = repository.getAllNotes();
   }

 public void insert(FavNews favNews) {
repository.insert(favNews);
 }



  public LiveData<List<FavNews>> getAllNotes() {
return allNotes;
}
 }
```

this is the repository

```
public class NewsRepository {
    private FavNewsDao favNewsDao;
    private LiveData<List<FavNews>> allNotes

    private NewsApi newsApi;
    private static NewsRepository newsRepository;


    public static NewsRepository getInstance() {
        if (newsRepository == null) {
            newsRepository = new NewsRepository();
        }
        return newsRepository;
    }

    private NewsRepository() {
        newsApi = RetrofitService.cteateService(NewsApi.class);
    }


    public MutableLiveData<NewsResponse> getNews(String key) {
        final MutableLiveData<NewsResponse> newsData = new MutableLiveData<>();
        newsApi.getNewsList(key).enqueue(new Callback<NewsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<NewsResponse> call,
                                   Response<NewsResponse> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    newsData.setValue(response.body());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<NewsResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                newsData.setValue(null);
            }
        });
        return newsData;
    }


    public NewsRepository(Application application) {
        FavNewsDatabase database = FavNewsDatabase.getInstance(application);
        favNewsDao = database.noteDao();
        allNotes = favNewsDao.getAllNotes();
    }

    public void insert(FavNews favNews) {
        new InsertNoteAsyncTask(favNewsDao).execute(favNews);
    }


    public LiveData<List<FavNews>> getAllNotes() {
        return allNotes;
    }

    private static class InsertNoteAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<FavNews, Void, Void> {
        private FavNewsDao favNewsDao;

        private InsertNoteAsyncTask(FavNewsDao favNewsDao) {
            this.favNewsDao = favNewsDao;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(FavNews... favNews) {
            favNewsDao.insert(favNews[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

like i said i tried everything in `Log` it shows me the strings but whenever i put the insert method code it gives me null what I am doing wronk please help thanks in advance..!

**EDIT**

```
NoteViewModel viewmodel;

 // and here 
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
         //here need to put insert method
          String a = articles.get(position).getWebTitle();
          String b = articles.get(position).getSectionName();
Log.e("test",a + b )
       everything till here works and i see the a + b in the log
     viewmodel.insert(new FavNews(a,b))     **here null exception**

  }
 });
```

**NEWS FRAGMENT**

```
public class NewsFragment extends Fragment {


    ArrayList<Result> articleArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    NewsAdapter newsAdapter;
    RecyclerView rvHeadline;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

    private static final String TAG = "NewsFragment";

    private NoteViewModel pageViewModel;

    public NewsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    public static NewsFragment newInstance() {
        return new NewsFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        pageViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(NoteViewModel.class);

    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup
            container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_fragment, container, false);
        rvHeadline = root.findViewById(R.id.rvNews);
        swipeRefreshLayout= root.findViewById(R.id.swip_refresh_layout);


        if (CheckInternet.isNetwork(getActivity())) {
            pageViewModel.getNewsRepository().observe(this, new
                    Observer<NewsResponse>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChanged(NewsResponse newsResponse) {
                            List<Result> newsArticles = newsResponse.getResponse().getResults();
                            articleArrayList.addAll(newsArticles);

                            newsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"something",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                if (CheckInternet.isNetwork(getActivity())) {
                    pageViewModel.getNewsRepository().observe(getActivity(), new Observer<NewsResponse>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChanged(NewsResponse newsResponse) {
                            List<Result> newsArticles = newsResponse.getResponse().getResults();
                            articleArrayList.addAll(newsArticles);

                            newsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"something",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });



        setupRecyclerView();

        return root;
    }

    private void setupRecyclerView() {
        if (newsAdapter == null) {
            newsAdapter = new NewsAdapter(getActivity(), articleArrayList);
            rvHeadline.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
            rvHeadline.setAdapter(newsAdapter);
            rvHeadline.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            rvHeadline.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
        } else {
            newsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is this code `Viewmodel.insert(new FavNews(String a,String b)`? And mentioned clearly where you get null in your code

Comment: I tried to put it in onbindView holder gets null
i tried to take the data in to fragment and tried there its null again

Comment: Please add what you tried in code, I will check and update you

Comment: I already said i tried it inside onBindView
I tried with interface to take the data and send it into fragment and tried in onCreatView and onActivityCreated  i tried all those.

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman I edited 1 option

Comment: Also add exception logs. What is null `viewmodel `, `articles` or what? have to know that

Comment: That means your `viewmodel ` is null. How do you initialize it?

Comment: in ViewModel I have insert method that calls insert from repository just check the codes please

Comment: I have seen your code. Probably you misunderstood java structure. You need class instance **[here viewModel]** to access property and method of that class. So, you have to initialize your `viewModel` before access its property. Hope you understand.

Comment: If you add your Fragment code, Then I will update it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after changing 1 line code into another method it work here was the problem..>!

```
repository = NewsRepository.getInstance();
```

just changing this into  from MutableLiveData into NoteViewModel method

```
 public class NoteViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {


 private NewsRepository repository;
  private LiveData<List<FavNews>> allNotes;



public MutableLiveData<NewsResponse> getNewsRepository() {
 repository = NewsRepository.getInstance();   //from here
return repository.getNews( "b70d396f-d5b4-43f0-8b67-222524937f25");
 }

public NoteViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
super(application);
 repository = NewsRepository.getInstance();    //// to here
repository = new NewsRepository(application);
allNotes = repository.getAllNotes();
 }

public void insert(FavNews favNews) {
repository.insert(favNews);
}



 public LiveData<List<FavNews>> getAllNotes() {
  return allNotes;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass `viewModel` instance from your fragment to adapter to access `insert` inside viewModel. Check below:

```
public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.NewsViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Result> articles;
    NoteViewModel viewModel;


    public NewsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Result> articles, NoteViewModel viewModel) {
        this.context = context;
        this.articles = articles;
        this.viewModel = viewModel;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NewsViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        ....

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //here need to put insert method
                String a = articles.get(position).getWebTitle();
                String b = articles.get(position).getSectionName();
                Log.e("test", a + b);
                //everything till here works and i see the a + b in the log
                viewmodel.insert(new FavNews(a, b)); /**here null exception **/

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then inside your call the `NewsAdapter` like below:

```
newsAdapter = new NewsAdapter(getActivity(), articleArrayList, pageViewModel);
```

**Now it should work.**

Comment: and what i need to pass in the fragment

Comment: i added the fragment

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.task.room, PID: 4817
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
inside the repository

Comment: That is different case @MikeB. Accept this one and post another with details stack trace. It's already complicated, don't make it long more. According SO, Ask one question in one thread. Hope you understand. Thanks

Comment: sorry but this didn't fix my problem

Comment: plus i have same      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.task.room.FavNewsDao.insert(com.task.room.FavNews)' on a null object reference

Comment: Then I am sorry mike, Spend lots of time to make your `ViewModel` workable. Now it comes to `Repository` and then probably in `Room`. Please move step by step. Not whole at a time. Thanks

Comment: @MikeB, Got help from anyone? You should respect other’s time and diligence. I saw your last post also

Comment: check the answer below